# Invalid packet length when connecting

Tags: netezza

Another team in my company commissioned a new server and installed Netezza on it, along with a bunch of internal programs. All of their programs that connect to Netezza are now giving this error:

```
A connection error has occurred: Invalid packet length
```

Attempting to connect to the database using a GUI such as DbVisualizer or RazorSQL gives the same error. Connecting to the "old" server still works fine. One of the differences between the two boxes is the Java version, 1.5 on the old one and 1.7 on the new one... not sure if that is relevant. (I'm not a Netezza expert, not really a Netezza user either!)

Any ideas?

Comment: Netezza is a Data Warehousing Appliance - you don't just "install" it. Perhaps you mean they installed the Netezza CLI so that you can access Netezza? Can you use nzsql to connect directly to the Netezza DB from the new machine?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance; I'm totally not a Netezza person. :) Just a  lowly Java dev... they thought this was Java related which was why I was brought in.

As far as I know (which isn't much!), a new Netezza DB was built, and this new server, let's call it NZ2, is the host you would specify in your JDBC connection. So maybe this NZ2 is the SMP master, and a farm of workers sit somewhere. Point is, there's a new Netezza DB and connecting thru JDBC fails.

I *can* connect thru nzsql when I'm on NZ2, but when I try to do the same from another Netezza box, let's say NZ1, nzsql seems to time out.

Comment: Oh, and just an update. Our DBA has opened a ticket with Netezza since this does not seem to be a Java issue.

Comment: And just to clarify: NZ1 and NZ2 do not "point" to the same Netezza database/system/whatever. They point to different ones. Completely separate. From my research, I should be able to use nzsql on NZ1 to connect to the Netezza system accessed from NZ2, but I get that timeout. Could be that NZ1 and NZ2 are in different realms, I don't know. Again, not a DBA or network engineer... just a dev. :) And even though they've opened the ticket with Netezza, I still am curious as to the cause and will anticipate Netezza's response.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use NZSQL on any system that has a network route to the Netezza Host machine(s). It sounds to me like there's a network issue between the new NZ box and your Java Application Server (and probably the rest of your network as well).  IBM should be able to help you guys resolve this though - be sure to let us know what ends up being the issue.

Comment: Very strange, as the box you buy usually comes with a tech person from ibm/netezza that connects, updates, initializes and tests everything before it's handed over. you dont 'build' a netezza box, you order it and it comes pre-configured in a rack. you just point it to where it should stand, and connect power and thernet and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression from the start that both NZ1 and NZ2 were running the same Netezza version. Apparently that was not the case.

The new NZ2 host was running against version 6.0 whereas NZ2 was running against 3.0. The JDBC driver we were using for NZ2 **was 3 major versions too old**. This also explains why the nzsql client on NZ1 couldn't connect to the NZ2 host.

We updated to the latest JDBC driver from IBM and can now connect just fine.